Interface Extend Issue with storybook react Material UI
Note
Simple Code in the end if anyone wishes to skip the actual problem faced and just focus on the issue
Problem Statement
Working on Storybook components and trying to reuse the MUI TextField, facing problem with creating own custom props that are extended from MUI Text field props
Actual Code
3 Primary files in the project
TextFieldConstants.ts
import { BaseTextFieldProps, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";

export interface CustomTextFieldProps extends BaseTextFieldProps {
    textFieldType: string;
    showDescription?: boolean;
    showLeadingIcon?: boolean,
    showTrailingIcon?: boolean,
}

export const TextFieldTypeOptions: {[key:string] : string} = {
    TextField: "TextField",
    LargeTextField: "LargeTextField",
    EmptyStateHelpText: "EmptyStateHelpText"
}

TextField.ts
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { styled } from '@mui/material';
import { TextFieldTypeOptions, CustomTextFieldProps } from "./TextFieldConstants";

const StyledCustomTextField = styled(TextField)({
   
})

const CustomTextField = ({textFieldType, showDescription, ...props}: CustomTextFieldProps) => {
    console.log(props);
    return ( 
        <StyledCustomTextField
            {...props}
            sx={
                textFieldType === TextFieldTypeOptions.EmptyStateHelpText ?
                {
                    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root" : {
                        "& fieldset" : {
                            border: "none"
                        }
                    }
                } :
                {}
            }
            defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
            helperText={showDescription ? props.helperText : ""}
        />
     );
}
 
export default CustomTextField;

TextFieldStories.tsx
import { useState } from 'react';
import CustomTextField from './TextField';
import { TextFieldTypeOptions, CustomTextFieldProps } from './TextFieldConstants';

const meta = {
    title: "DLSCOMPONENTS/TextField",
    tags: ["autodocs"],
    component: CustomTextField,
    argTypes: {
        textFieldType: {
            control: {type: "select"},
            options: Object.values(TextFieldTypeOptions),
            description: "type of the text field"
        },
        defaultValue: {
            control: {type: "text"},
            description: "Value to show for uncontrolled component"
        },
        showDescription: {
            control: {type: "boolean"},
            description: "Shows helper text if true"
        }
    }
}

export const EmptyStateHelpText = {
    args: {
        textFieldType: TextFieldTypeOptions.EmptyStateHelpText,
        defaultValue: "Title Help Text",
        helperText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore",
        showDescription: true
    }
}

export const TextField = {
    args: {
        textFieldType: TextFieldTypeOptions.TextField,
        showLeadingIcon: false,
        showTrailingIcon: false,
    },
    render: (args: CustomTextFieldProps) => {
        const [value, setValue] = useState("Default");

        const handleChange = (event) => {
            setValue(event.target.value);
        }
        return (
            <CustomTextField {...args} value={value} onChange={handleChange} /> 
        )
    }
}

export default meta;

Error Faced
getting below error on onChange if i use BaseTextFieldProps
Type '{ value: string; onChange: (event: any) => void; textFieldType: string; showDescription?: boolean; autoComplete?: string; autoFocus?: boolean; children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<TextFieldClasses>; ... 288 more ...; component?: ElementType<...>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CustomTextFieldProps'.
  Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CustomTextFieldProps'.ts(2322)

If I extend using TextFieldProps I get below error on interface extend line
An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

Analysis and Requirement
I am not sure why TextFieldProps does not work
I understand onChange and other event handlers are declared on derived interfaces and probably need to extend from either of the 3 (StandardTextFieldProps, FilledTextFieldProps, OutlinedTextFieldProps - refer textfield.d.ts for more info) but my primary aim was to extend the functionality of MUI textfield, so basically take all coming from MUI and add own props in it
Note
New to storybook, please also share how the prop types are usually handled here and any other insights in the code if possible
Simple Code for the crux of the problem


import TextField, { BaseTextFieldProps, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";

export interface CustomTextFieldProps extends BaseTextFieldProps {
    textFieldType: string;
    showDescription?: boolean
}

const CustomTextField = ({textFieldType, showDescription, ...props}: CustomTextFieldProps) => {
    return ( 
        <TextField
            {...props}
            defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
            helperText={showDescription ? props.helperText : ""}
        />
     );
}

export const NewComponent = () => {
    
    const handleChange = () => {
        console.log('handle Change')
    }

    return (
        <CustomTextField 
            onChange={handleChange}
        /> 
    )
}
 
export default CustomTextField;



